# tensorflow map_fn with a list of list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensor

I'm trying to pass a list of arguments to a function using `tensorflow` function: `tf.map_fn`. Here is my code:

```py
def my_func(a,v,c,d):
    print(a,v,c,d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.config.set_visible_devices(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')[0],'GPU')

    iterable = [['a','b','c','s'],['s','e','f','c']]
    tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(iterable)
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tensor)
    tf.map_fn(lambda x: my_func(*x),dataset)
```

But I'm getting this error I can't really decipher:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/WorkSSD/Notebooks/01 Convert Raw EDF to Raw CSV copy.py", line 134, in <module>
    tf.map_fn(lambda x: my_func(*x),dataset)
  File "/Users/fabiomagarelli/.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 629, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/fabiomagarelli/.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 561, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/fabiomagarelli/.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/map_fn.py", line 640, in map_fn_v2
    return map_fn(
  File "/Users/fabiomagarelli/.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 561, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/fabiomagarelli/.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/map_fn.py", line 392, in map_fn
    result_flat_signature = [
  File "/Users/fabiomagarelli/.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/map_fn.py", line 393, in <listcomp>
    _most_general_compatible_type(s)._unbatch()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/Users/fabiomagarelli/.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 4587, in _unbatch
    raise ValueError("Slicing dataset elements is not supported for rank 0.")
ValueError: Slicing dataset elements is not supported for rank 0.
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You could print it like this if your goal is to print.

```
import tensorflow as tf

if __name__ == '__main__':

    iterable = [['a','b','c','s'],['s','e','f','c']]
    tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(iterable)
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tensor)
    for element in dataset:
        print(element)
```

This works too.

```
def my_func(a):
    tf.print(a,[a])
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':

    iterable = [[['a','b','c','s'],['s','e','f','c']]]
    tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(iterable)
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tensor)
    iterator = iter(dataset)
    tf.map_fn(my_func, iterator.get_next())
```